# Gridsplitter stretch limits - WPF

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I would like to set some limits/boundaries on the amount of pixels we can stretch a gridsplitter control which is inside a grid.How is this possible?
Basically one should not be allowed to pull the gridsplitter to large limits(it should be restricted to smaller grid boundaries)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` on the `ColumnDefinition` class.